# Azure Cognitive Search - Create Data Souce via API

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an azure cognitive search service that I am trying to add an azure blob storage data source via the api. Creating it works fine via the portal.

Here is the uri:

```
https://xxxxxx.search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2019-05-06
```

Here are the headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json  
api-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host: XXXXXXXXXX.search.windows.net
Content-Length: 412
```

Here is the body:

```
{
    "name" : "documents",  
    "description" : "documents data source",  
    "type" : "'azureblob",
    "credentials" : 
     { "connectionString" :
        "XXXXXXXXX"
     },
    "container" : { "name" : "documents" }  
}
```

When I run it, I get a 400 error code with the following message:

> {"error":{"code":"","message":"Data source type ''azureblob' is not
>   supported"}}

I got the enum value straight from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source).  Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So it was a copy/paste error from the docs:
"azureblob" <> "azureblob "

Comment: There is also an extra quote in the code you included above.